# Google Sheets' Function ROW interval

Tags: google-sheets

I'm implementing a spreadsheet and I needed to define a ROW function in which I have a range from cell B2 to the last cell filled. I'm trying somehow like in the function below but it's not working. Is there any way to write this code into the ROW function that works the way I need?

```
=ROW(B2:B&COUNTA(B2:B))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure which one you need (arrayed output or single cell output) so here you go:

- **`=ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B)))`**
- **`=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("B2:B"&COUNTA(B2:B))))`**